# What is the Xpath to IMPORTXML to get the full <link> tag which have the @hreflang attribute

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to import all  tag which has the attribute [hreflang]. So far, I can only able to import the attribute value using the following formula.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://allbirds.eu","//link[@hreflang]/@href")
```

Now I am getting the target attribute value only (for example @href in this case: `https://fr-FR.allbirds.eu/`). I can not import the tag itself.
I want to import the tag itself. My expected result is `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://de-DE.allbirds.eu/">`

Please give me your suggestion which xpath can give me the result?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://allbirds.eu")` to a cell.

```js
const SAMPLE = url => [...UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().matchAll(/<link[\w\s\S].+?>/g)].flatMap(([e]) => e.includes("hreflang") ? [e] : []);
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your URL of `https://allbirds.eu`. When you changed the URL, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

### Added:

I thought that `IMPORTXML` cannot directly retrieve the value including the tag like `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://de-DE.allbirds.eu/">`. So I proposed to use Google Apps Script. But, from your following reply,

> But I'm looking for a solution with XPATH. Apps Script is my last option.

If you are required to use `IMPORTXML` and the xpath, how about the following sample formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("<link rel=""alternate"" hreflang="""&IMPORTXML("https://allbirds.eu","//link[@hreflang]/@hreflang")&""" href="""&IMPORTXML("https://allbirds.eu","//link[@hreflang]/@href")&""" />")
```

In this case, the same result with the above sample Google Apps Script can be obtained.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. But I'm looking for a solution with XPATH. Apps Script is my last option.

Comment: @Amir Hossain Thank you for replying. I thought that `IMPORTXML` cannot directly retrieve the value including the tag like `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://de-DE.allbirds.eu/">`. So I proposed to use Google Apps Script. I apologize for this. From your replying, I added a sample formula using `IMPORTXML` and the xpath. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.